# Display posts where tag matches page title

Tags: php, wordpress, loops, tags, custom-post-type

I'm trying to create a loop that displays a list of posts with a tag that matches the page title that the loop is on.

For example, I have a list of custom post types called 'countries' and within each country I have a recent posts list. For each country I want to display posts with a tag relevant to that country. So if a post contains the tag 'UK' then only these posts should be displayed on the 'UK' page.

Here's my code so far which does not work at all...

```
    $country_tag = get_the_title(); 

    global $wp_query;
    $args = array(
    'tag__in' => 'post_tag', //must use tag id for this field
    'posts_per_page' => -1); //get all posts

    $posts = get_posts($args);
    foreach ($posts as $post) :
    //do stuff 
    if ( $posts = $country_tag ) {
    the_title();
    }
    endforeach;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Assuming that** you've got the correct value in `$country_tag`, and **assuming that** (per your question) `$country_tag` is the tag *name* (and not the tag slug or ID), then you must either use the [Taxonomy Parameters](https://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/get_posts#Taxonomy_Parameters) in your get_posts, or first get the ID or slug of the tag.  You can do this using [get_term_by](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_term_by)

Additionally, before you can operate on the post, you need to call [setup_postdata](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/setup_postdata).

I recommend using the `get_term_by` first, so you can first check if the tag exists and output a message if it does not.

```
$country_tag = get_the_title(); 

$tag = get_term_by( 'name', $country_tag, 'post_tag' );

if ( ! $country_tag || ! $tag ) {
    echo '<div class="error">Tag ' . $country_tag . ' could not be found!</div>';
} else {
    // This is not necessary.  Remove it...
    // global $wp_query;
    $args = array(
        'tag__in'        => (int)$tag->term_id,
        'posts_per_page' => -1
    );

    $posts = get_posts( $args );
    // be consistent - either use curly braces OR : and endif
    foreach( $posts as $post ) {
        // You can't use `the_title`, etc. until you do this...
        setup_postdata( $post );
        // This if statement is completely unnecessary, and is incorrect - it's an assignment, not a conditional check
        // if ( $posts = $country_tag ) {
            the_title();
        // }
    }
}
```

Above I am recommending the `get_term_by` method, because it allows you to first validate that there **is a tag** with that name.  If you were 100% confident that there is always a tag that corresponds to the page title, you could use the taxonomy parameters (demonstrated below):

```
$country_tag = get_the_title(); 

$args = array(
    'tax_query' => array(
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'post_tag',
            'field'    => 'name',
            'terms'    => $country_tag
        )
    ),
    'posts_per_page' => -1
);

$posts = get_posts( $args );
foreach( $posts as $post ) {
    setup_postdata( $post );
    the_title();
}
```

Comment: I added the tag 'united kingdom' to a post and the page I am viewing as the title 'united kingdom'. However using the loop you have kindly put together unfortunately returns nothing.

Comment: wait ignore that... the first loop you provided worked. The second loop returned nothing... i think you did it :)